# Example of a space which is Hausdorff and locally Euclidean but not paracompact?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

On page 330 of John G. Ratcliffe's text on hyperbolic manifolds, he defines a manifold $M$ to be a locally Euclidean Hausdorff space. By locally Euclidean, he means as usual that for each $x \in M$ there is an open neighbour $U$ of $x$ which is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

But he omits the usual paracompactness assumption. I would guess that $M$ being locally Euclidean and Hausdorff is not sufficient to imply that it is paracompact, given [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527642/the-equivalence-between-paracompactness-and-second-countablity-in-a-locally-eucl) from Lee's book.

Does anyone know of such a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)). $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Note that every metrizable space is paracompact and $\mathbb R^n$ with usual topology is metrizable.

Comment: Also, a paracompact Hausdorff locally metrizable space is metrizable. So for manifolds, paracompactness and metrizable are equivalent.